# ¿Cómo crear una cantidad de variables en función a un valor ingresado?

Tags: python, poo

**¡Hola comunidad!**

Tengo la duda acerca cómo poder crear una serie de variables de acuerdo a un valor ingresado como argumento de una función/método. El siguiente código sirve como ejemplo:

```
class mis_vectores():

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def cantidad(self, num):
        # Método para crear variables en función al número que reciba como argumento
        cantidad_vectores = num

        if cantidad_vectores == 1:

            self.vector_1 = 0

        elif cantidad_vectores == 2:

            self.vector_1 = 0
            self.vector_2 = 0

        elif cantidad_vectores == 3:

            self.vector_1 = 0
            self.vector_2 = 0
            self.vector_3 = 0

        # ...Y así sucesivamente

ejemplo = mis_vectores()
ejemplo.cantidad(3)
```

En este ejemplo, el método `cantidad` reciba un parámetro `num` para crear vectores de acuerdo a este número. Para cantidades relativamente pequeñas es sencillo implementar los condicionales `if`, `elif` y `else` y crear, en cada uno, las respectivas variables de tipo `self.vector_i`.

Ahora, imaginemos que el argumento que ingresamos a `cantidad` sea, por ejemplo, `25`. No sería muy práctico tener que añadir 25 bloques condicionales y crear, en cada uno, las variables de tipo `self.vector_i`, `self.vector_i+1`, ... hasta `self.vector_n`. Se tendrían demasiadas líneas de código y, además, el programa fallaría si, por ejemplo, se llegase a ingresar un argumento de `cantidad`mayor que 25 (`ejemplo.cantidad(26)`, `ejemplo.cantidad(40)`, etc).

¡Gracias de antemano por sus comentarios!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por poder, puedes usar `setattr` y un simple ciclo `for`:

```
class MisVectores:

    def cantidad(self, num):
        for n in range(1, num + 1):
            setattr(self, f"vector_{n}", 0)          


ejemplo = MisVectores()
ejemplo.cantidad(3)
print(ejemplo.vector_1)
```

Ahora bien, personalmente ante este tipo de problemas, tu clase parece actuar como un contenedor/administrador de un conjunto homogéneo de objetos, prefiero no añadir atributos en tiempo de ejecución sino usar un contenedor. Puedes usar un diccionario. Si quieres acceder a los objetos como un atributo de la instancia simplemente define el método `__getattr__` (y/o reimplementa `__setattr__`):

```
class MisVectores():

    def __init__(self):
        self._vectores = {}

    def agregar_vectores(self, num):
        for n in range(len(self._vectores) + 1, num + len(self._vectores) + 1):
            self._vectores[f"vector_{n}"] = 0

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        if (attr:= self._vectores.get(name)) is not None:
            return attr
        raise AttributeError(
            f"'{self.__class__.__name__}' object has no attribute '{name}'"
            ) 

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        spl = name.split("_")
        if len(spl) == 2 and spl[0] == "vector" and spl[1].isdigit():
            vectores = self._vectores[name] = value
            return
        super().__setattr__(name, value)



ejemplo = MisVectores()
ejemplo.agregar_vectores(3)
print(ejemplo.vector_2)
ejemplo.agregar_vectores(3)
print(ejemplo.vector_6)
ejemplo.vector_6 = 5
print(ejemplo.vector_6)
```

Sin duda es más complicado, pero tiene sus ventajas. Ahora tienes todos los objetos "vector" almacenados en un diccionario que es atributo de instancia, están separados y aislados del resto de atributos/métodos de la clase facilitando enormemente su manejo, eliminación o adición por parte de la clase y cualquiera de sus métodos. Además el acceso a ellos mediante "dot notation" (`instancia.atributo`) no difiere.

---

Explicación de algunos conceptos planteados en comentarios:

- El uso de `_` (un solo guion) antes del nombre de un atributo (`self._vectores`), variable, método o función es solo **una convención que indica que es "privado"**. No tiene significado alguno para el lenguaje (los atributos/métodos privados no existen en Python), solo es una señal para otro desarrollador que básicamente dice "ésto debes considerarlo de uso privado e interno de la clase, no debe ser accedido o modificado directamente, si lo haces se supone que sabes lo que haces, luego no vengas llorando si todo explota... XD".
- La sentencia `attr:= self._vectores.get(name))` no tiene mucho de especial, `self._vectores` es un diccionario, `get` es el método `dict.get` que obtiene el valor asociado de una clave (`name`) si existe o retorna un valor por defecto si no lo hace (por defecto `None`).
  `attr:=` es una expresión de asignación o operador "walrus" (morsa por la forma `:=`) introducidas en Python 3.8. Simplemente permie asignar un valor a una variable en la misma sentencia condicional que la evalúa, es equivalente en éste caso a:

  ```
  attr = self._vectores.get(name)
  if attr is not None:
      # ...
  ```

  Lo que hacemos es ver si existe la clave `name` en el diccionario, si existe la retornamos como si fuera un atributo y si no lanzamos una excepción.
- La sentencia `super().__getattribute__("_vectores")[name] = value` lo que hace es invocar al método `__getattribute__` del padre de la clase (`super`) y delegar en en el la resolución del atributo `self._vectores`.

  El método `__getattribute__` es el primer método encargado de la resolución de atributos, cuando hacemos `instancia.método/instancia.attributo` el primero en invocarse es él, exista o no dicho método/atributo. Toda clase tiene dicho método implementado y es heredadado de `object`.

  Por lo tanto, `super().__getattribute__("_vectores") obtiene una referencia a`self._vectores`y`[name] = value`  crea una nueva clave y le asigna su valor en dicho diccionario.

  Realmente en éste caso no es necesario delegar en el padre, no con la implementación actual, basta con `vectores = self._vectores[name] = value`. Inicialmente no incluí el condicional previo y en ese caso era necesario para evitar la recursión infinita. He modificado el código arriba también, pero dejo de todas forma la explicación aquí.
- El método `__getattr__` es invocado en última instancia si la obtención del atributo siguiendo toda la cadena de resolución ha fallado, básicamente si el atributo no existe ni en la clase ni heredado, ni es una `property`, ni un método, etc. No está implementado por defecto y hay que tener en cuenta que se llama siempre el último, `__getattibute__` es llamado antes siempre.
- Por último `super().__setattr__(name, value)` de nuevo delega en el modo `__setattr__` del padre (`object` en éste caso). El método `__setattr__` es el hermano de `__getattribute__`, es invocado siempre que se realiza una asignación a un atributo `instancia.atributo = valor`. Como reimplementamos el método en la clase hija para poder asignar valores a los "atributos" del diccionario mediante `instancia.vector_n = valor`, si el atributo no es uno de los que vive en `self._diccionario` debemos delegar en el método del padre, para el resto de atributos.

Es un tema complejo que implica a toda la implementación de la POO en Python y que da no solo para otra publicación, sino para varias. Algunos preguntas relacionadas que pueden ayudar:

- [¿Qué es y que utilidad tiene super en POO?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/130241/15089)
- [RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/351477/15089)

Comment: Desconocía que existieran los constructores `__getattr__`  y `__setattr__`. Ya me encuentro investigando acerca de ellos. Ahora, entre algunas de las dudas acerca de su respuesta me encuentro con: 

1. ¿Qué significa que la variable self._vectores tenga un carácter "_" después de self.?

2. ¿Por qué la variable `self._vectores` se concatena con `[f"vector_{n}"]`?

3. ¿Qué ocurre internamente a la intérprete de Python con las sentencias `(attr:= self._vectores.get(name))`, `super().__getattribute__("_vectores")[name] = value` y `super().__setattr__(name, value)`

Comment: @gv-pro, he editado la respuesta. He intentado explicarlo todo por encima, como menciono el tema es algo complejo en lo eferente a `__getattr__`, `__getatributte__` y `__setattr__`.  Si tienes dudas de importancia concretas sobre dichos métodos puedes crear una nueva pregunta, dan para una...